# Oracle - DELETE Rows based on Raw Column values

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle, sql-delete

I want to do the following with my code, and I'm not sure where to begin:

say I have a class that contains a `Byte()` ID field:

```
Public Class Message
    Public Property ID as Byte()
    '...
End Class
```

and those `Message`s are stored in the database, with the ID stored as a RAW column.

Given `Messages = List(Of Message)`, how would I go about deleting all of the messages in the list?

I've got as far as:

```
Dim sql as String = "DELETE FROM TableName WHERE IDColumn IN ("
For Each msg in Messages
    sql = sql + msg.ID ' I don't think this will work
Next
sql = sql + ")"

Using oCommand As New OracleCommand(sql)
' ...
```

> Note: The IDColumn isn't actually a primary key column or anything -
>   it's just another column (as per spec, unfortunately).

Comment: Your approach is fine -- the ids don't need to be primary keys.  However, they do need comma between them and quotes if they are strings or dates.

Comment: It doesn't matter that IDColumn is not the primary key, as any column can be used to limit records in the WHERE clause. Only, it is a strange name for a column which is not the table's primary key.

Comment: but I can't use a + operator with Byte() and String - so there must be another approach to put the id into the SQL string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two things wrong with my code:

1. I needed to include the commas between the items (see [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32203784/318414))
2. I forgot the single quotes around the ID values
3. I needed to convert the Byte() to a string of hex values:

`String.Join(String.Empty, msg.ID.Select(Function(id) id.ToString("X2")))`

So that my loop looks like:

```
For Each msg in Messages
    sql = sql + "'" + String.Join(String.Empty, msg.ID.Select(Function(id) id.ToString("X2"))) + "'"
Next
```

Comment: To hex? So you get `IN (01,0F,1A)`instead of `IN (1,15,26)`? This should result in a syntax error in SQL. Using Join and Select is a great idea, but use `id.ToString()` instead of `id.ToString("X2")`.

Comment: each messageID is a Byte Array, so it's `IN('010F','4D32')`. Maybe it would work with a straight `ToString()`, I didn't try it - but the hex seems to work fine. When I open Oracle SQL Developer, I see the hex string displayed - so it makes sense that it would compare with that.

Comment: Okay, I misread and thought each ID to be an ID rather than an array of IDs. So the column IDColumn is obviously a string that holds a list of IDs in hex Format glued together. Strange way of storing the data. Especially as '0A1F' wouldn't match '1F0A' in spite of holding the same IDs. But well, I am glad you found a solution.

Comment: no, it's not an array of IDs - it's a single ID, which is a byte array - so '010F' is a single ID, made up of two bytes, stored in an array in VB.net

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the commas in your list, so IDs 1, 2, and 3 make `IN (123)`. You can use this loop instead:

```
For Each msg in Messages
    sql = sql + msg.ID + ","
Next

sql= sql.Substring(0, sql.Length - 1) + ")";
```

Or even so, provided IDColumn  cannot be null:

```
Dim sql as String = "DELETE FROM TableName WHERE IDColumn IN (null"
For Each msg in Messages
    sql = sql + ", " + msg.ID
Next
sql = sql + ")"
```

This would also deal with the case Messages is empty, whereas in the first example you should check this in order not to end up with `IN ()` which would result in a syntax error.

Comment: If I use `sql = sql + msg.ID + ","`, I get the error "`Operator + is not defined for types 1-dimensional array of byte and String`" - so I can't use that...

Comment: Okay, I don't know vb.net so well. If byte doesn't convert automatically then do it manually: `String.ToString(msg.ID)`.

Comment: `ToString` won't work - see my answer. Thanks for your help though, and pointing out the commas thing :)